# Adapter from C++ output stream to an Android TextView or equivalent?

Tags: c++, text, android-ndk, outputstream

Porting a C++ app to Android JNI... would like to route C++ cout and cerr to an Android TextView or similar display for testing purposes. Is there an open source JNI adapter that does this already? If not, I would like some hints on how to write such an adapter in a quick & dirty fashion. Thanks for helping this Android n00b.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, use Android's native logging facility.

```
#include <android/log.h>

__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "MyProject", "Hello world");
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "MyProject", "The value is %d", value);
```

In the Android.mk, add liblog to the link source list:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see rewriting our macros to use these. But I am still interested in watching the messages come up on the Android screen in "real time".

Comment: Does it have to be the Android screen (as opposed to your debugger)? And does it have to be cout/cerr? A phone screen is not best utilized by emulating a console. That said, you can pass your homegrown OutputStreams to the JNI library and have it write bytes to it all you want (via JNI calls). What happens to the bytes on the other side is up to you. You can route them to a TextView or anything. There are many facets to this approach; not sure which one are you asking about. But using it for debug output is an overkill.

Comment: I want to run our existing Linux command line app in the Android emulator without rewriting all of its console output, for initial testing purposes. Anything that resembles a "console" will work. It does not need to be the (emulated) phone screen. Clearly the Android logger is the appropriate choice for deployment, but I am at the proof-of-concept stage.

Comment: Then check out the ADB tool. It lets you connect to and Android device or emulator in a remote shell manner, and run Linux utilities as they are. Note that the Linux code needs to be compiled into a standalone executable for this, not into a JNI library. NDK won't help you much here.